# Как закруглить одну сторону меню?

Tags: css

Как закруглить одну сторону меню? Пишу в стили вот такой код:

```
.SuperMenu {
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
}
```

И ничего не работает!

Answer (score 3):

Вам, я так понимаю, надо закгруглить два нижних угла.

```
.corner-bottom { 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 24px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 24px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 24px; 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 24px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 24px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 24px; 
}
```

- проблемы с IE никто не отменял ))

Comment: не получается может как нить в html это сделать?

Comment: Вы через какой браузер смотрите?:)

Comment: Все работает, кроме ie7-ie8. Вот тут есть удобный генератор http://border-radius.com/

Comment: `-o-border-radius` тоже сразу допишите :)